# How to get a disk IO time rate from prometheus

Tags: metrics, rate, prometheus-node-exporter, disk-io

I have a server running standard Prometheus node exporter. Metrics are properly collected.
Now I need to display in Grafana rate of time spend for IO operations on all devices.

In the /metrics for my server I am getting the following (among other metrics)

```
# HELP node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total The weighted # of seconds spent doing I/Os.
# TYPE node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total counter
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-0"} 3800.91
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-1"} 37118.635
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-2"} 129.778
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-3"} 3475.8250000000003
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-4"} 8.892
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-5"} 6210.612
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-6"} 14.934000000000001
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-7"} 2228.0750000000003
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="dm-8"} 1029.349
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="sda"} 20042.765
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="sdb"} 137.591
node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{device="sr0"} 0.007
```

I wrote the following query

```
rate(sum by(device)(node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{instance="myserver:9100"}))[1m]
```

and I got parsing error message: "**parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors**"
If I take out [1m] from the query it suppose to reverse to default interval of 1 second, but I am getting different parsing error message: "**parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "rate", got instant vector**"
I am pretty new to PromQL, so forgive me if I do not yet understand its functions details, but I someone point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix my query, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: [First apply rate, then sum.](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate/)

Comment: I did apply rate first but got the same error messages

Comment: Your query should be like this: `sum by(device)(rate(node_disk_io_time_weighted_seconds_total{instance="myserver:9100"} [1m]))`. If it is, no error should occur.

Comment: My bad. I had extra parentheses in the query. I.e. instead of  {...}[1m] I had (metric{...})[1m]. Now it is working